# Unity3d, C# : Totally lost with ridiculous errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since a month I'm hardly following tutorials and learning C# when I have free time and I feel more and more confident even if my skills still suck.

Now I challenge myself to mix 2 grid-based tutorials to have the shape of one and the performance of the other, and I'm really frustrated because I'm only at the beginning and I'm already stuck. I know mixing codes is not always an easy task because of their logics, but the errors I have... Guys, I swear I tried to fix it by myself. Si I took off all the mixes and only kept the concerned bloc with errors to continue.

Look at that:
- Assets\Scripts\Grid.cs(28,37): error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
- Assets\Scripts\Grid.cs(28,40): error CS0103: The name 'z' does not exist in the current context
I have both of those 6 times, compressed in 3 lines of code...  **They look ridiculous!** *Please kill me.*

Here's a screenshot, in case:
[grrr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWi7T.jpg)

And here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int gridX, gridZ;
    private int[,] gridArray;
    private float cellSize;

    void Start()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid(gridX, gridZ, 1f);
    }

    public Grid(int gridX, int gridZ, float cellSize)
    {
        this.gridX = gridX;
        this.gridZ = gridZ;
        this.cellSize = cellSize;

        gridArray = new int[gridX, gridZ];

        for(int x = 0; x < gridArray.GetLength(0); x++) ;
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < gridArray.GetLength(1); z++) ;
            {
                Utils.CreateWorldText(gridArray[x, z].ToString(), null, GetWorldPosition(x, z) + new Vector3(cellSize, 0, cellSize) * .5f, 10, Color.white, TextAnchor.MiddleCenter);
                Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(x, z), GetWorldPosition(x, z + 1), Color.white, 3600f);
                Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(x, z), GetWorldPosition(x + 1, z), Color.white, 3600f);
            }
        }
        Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(0, gridZ), GetWorldPosition(gridX, gridZ), Color.white, 3600f);
        Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(gridX, 0), GetWorldPosition(gridX, gridZ), Color.white, 3600f);
    }

    private Vector3 GetWorldPosition(int x, int z)
    {
        return new Vector3(x, 0, z) * cellSize;
    }
}

public class Utils [...]
```

The worse in this story is that I already did that tutorial and the first time I didn't have any issue with that bloc. Tried to paste it, issues remained, checked, checked², etc... No way. Any ideas?

Comment: In cases like this (assuming this is in VS), try doing `CTRL-A`, `CTRL-K-F` to auto-format. That should make what's going on a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you @Chris :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put off ; at the for loops

```
   for(int x = 0; x < gridArray.GetLength(0); x++) ;  <===
   for(int z = 0; z < gridArray.GetLength(1); z++) ;  <===
```

---

```
    for(int x = 0; x < gridArray.GetLength(0); x++) 
    {
        for(int z = 0; z < gridArray.GetLength(1); z++) 
        {
            Utils.CreateWorldText(gridArray[x, z].ToString(), null, GetWorldPosition(x, z) + new Vector3(cellSize, 0, cellSize) * .5f, 10, Color.white, TextAnchor.MiddleCenter);
            Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(x, z), GetWorldPosition(x, z + 1), Color.white, 3600f);
            Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(x, z), GetWorldPosition(x + 1, z), Color.white, 3600f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also after the other one `for(int z = 0; z < gridArray.GetLength(1); z++) ;`

Comment: Damn... The worst is I know I can't do this.
Thank you guys @Frenchy and StepTNT